# Searching other fields in the internal backoffice search box - v7.1.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7, examine

My aim is to add additional fields to the searching parameters for the internal search - I have amended `ExamineIndex.config` to index the new property:

```
<IndexSet SetName="InternalIndexSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Internal/">
    <IndexUserFields>
        <add Name="briefing"/>
    </IndexUserFields>
</IndexSet>
```

However, after rebuilding the internal index, it seems as though the internal search is only using the node name.

Is it possible to search multiple properties with the internal search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right - the `Content` and `Media` searches only take into account the Node Name, along with a path restriction if the current user has a starting node specified.

`Member` search also includes the following additional fields:

- email
- loginName

As a reference, see the implementation here:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/src/Umbraco.Web/Editors/EntityController.cs#L227-L283

If you want to implement a custom search, you'd have to create a plugin or dashboard that would allow you to implement the search features you want.

For some ideas, checkout the MemberListView project (which uses custom examine searching to populate the list): https://github.com/robertjf/umbMemberListView